# persistence.xml in EAR and JAR file. Which to use

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have an application that is packed in a JAR file (my EJB files). This is then packed in an EAR file.

Both of these packages have their own **persistence.xml** file. Which one does glassfish (or any server for that matter) use? Does it look at both files? Or only one of them?

Answer (score 1):

> Which one does glassfish (or any server for that matter) use?

According to [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1387388953_6850445b2ced2c970425623880555eb8):

> 8.2 Persistence Unit Packaging
>
> Within Java EE environments, an EJB-JAR, WAR, EAR, or application client JAR can define a persis-
> tence unit. Any number of persistence units may be defined within these scopes.
> A persistence unit may be packaged within one or more jar files contained within a WAR or EAR, as a
> set of classes within an EJB-JAR file or in the WAR classes directory, or as a combination of these
> as defined below...

Edit:

> If I have a persistence unit defined in both XML files with the same name, which one will it use?

By default the one defined in your .jar.

> 8.2.2 Persistence Unit Scope
>
> A persistence unit that is defined at the level of the EAR is generally visible to all components
> in the application. However, if a persistence unit of the same name is defined by an EJB-JAR,
> WAR, or application jar file within the EAR, the persistence unit of that name defined at EAR
> level will not be visible to the components defined by that EJB-JAR, WAR, or application jar
> file unless the persistence unit reference uses the persistence unit name # syntax to specify a
> path name to disambiguate the reference...

Comment: yes, but it doesnt say which one it will use over the other. If I have a persistence unit defined in both XML files with the same name, which one will it use?